# Pass reference to a function in C

Tags: c, parameters, reference

I tried to construct a function that has the reference as a parameter.

But the compile gave me a error warning, saying that expected')', I don't know what is the problem. 
Can't we use reference as parameter in C?
The following is the code segment.

```
typedef struct Qnode{
    struct Qnode* first;
    struct Qnode* rear;
    int value;
}Queue;

int init_Queue(Queue &q)  //expected')'  as the compiler warned me.
{
    return 1;
}
```

Should I use a pointer instead of a reference as a parameter??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't have references.  That's a C++ construct.

You'll need to change the function to accept a pointer.

```
int init_Queue(Queue *q)
{
    printf("value=%d\n", q->value);
    return 1;
}
```